# Filling a one2many inside a one2many in onchange

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

Using an on_change method I am trying to send default values to a one2many field using the concept of (0,0, {list values}; even there it works fine but inside that one2many there is also a one2many field to which I must also send values to implement In my code the same concept of (0,0, {list values}, but I did not get success.

Could you help me?.

Attached fragment of my code

```py
class hc(models.Model):
    _name = 'hc'
    laboratorios_ids = fields.One2many(
        string='Laboratorios', comodel_name='resullab',
        inverse_name='hc_id')

    def cargar_pool_labs(self):
        labs = []
        pool = self.env['mymodel'].sudo().search([])
        for laboratorio in pool:
            analitos = [(0, 0, {'analito': line.analito,
                                'resultado': line.resultado ,
                                'resultado2': line.resultado2 ,
                                'unidades': line.unidades })
                            for line in laboratorio.analitos_ids]
            labs.append((0,0,{
            'nombre_examen' : laboratorio.nombre_examen,
            'cups' : laboratorio.cups,
            'laboratorio_id': laboratorio.laboratorio_id,
            'analitos_ids' : analitos
            }))
        self.laboratorios_ids = labs
```

*Note: the analitos_ids field is the one2many field that is inside the laboratorios_ids field which is also one2many.*

The others models extructure

```py
class resullab(models.Model):
    _name = 'resullab'
    analitos_ids = fields.One2many('analito','laboratorio_id',
                                   'Analitos Lab', ondelete='cascade')

class labs_analito(models.Model):
    _name = 'analito'
    laboratorio_id = fields.Many2one('laboratorios', 'Lab Parent')
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: Please specify model structures, which many2one fields are there.

Comment: @EmiproTechnologiesPvt.Ltd. Thanks for replying, I have added more information on the models.

Comment: I have updated answer, review it.

Answer (score 3):

The only reason I can see here is the missing many2one reference in **analitos**. This **'analitos_ids' : analitos** refers to which many2one model that record id must be specified.

```
def cargar_pool_labs(self):
  labs = []    
  pool = self.env['mymodel'].sudo().search([])
  for laboratorio in pool:
      analitos = [(0, 0, {'analito': line.analito, 'resultado': line.resultado , 'resultado2': line.resultado2 , 'unidades':            line.unidades, }) for line in laboratorio.analitos_ids]
      labs.append((0,0,{'nombre_examen' : laboratorio.nombre_examen,
     'cups' : laboratorio.cups, 'laboratorio_id': laboratorio.laboratorio_id.id, 'analitos_ids' : analitos}))
  self.laboratorios_ids = labs
```

And one more thing many2one reference must be id not an object. In your code it's an object not ID.

```
'laboratorio_id': laboratorio.laboratorio_id.id
```

> **Solution:**
>
> The many2one field **'hc_id'** in **resullab** model is missing.
>
> ```
> 'hc_id' : self.id #(here the id of 'hc' model required).
> ```
>
> **analitos = [(0, 0, {'hc_id': id of resullab_object.id})]**

This might helps you.

[Filling default value for one2many model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41185336/set-default-value-while-creating-record-from-one2many-field-odoo)

Comment: I understand the point, the problem is that the id does not exist since it is being created in an on_change, the register is presented as a NewId and I still do not have access to resullab.id

Comment: Without that reference it will create records but not linked to any many2one so it won't displayed on screen. You can check it in database, records will be there.

Comment: @EmiproTechnologiesPvt.Ltd. i hope you agree with my answer all respect to you

Answer (score 1):

sorry about my english.

1- onchange is a method called from the client side on the server this 
   method will return a value to the client side (javascript).

2- so when the client receive this data will fillup the fields so in the current
   view that you are in (form) if the field is not there the value will be
   ignored.

3- so when you pass the values of the second o2m field in the view this field is not there
   because it's in the form that will be opened by clicking on additem or
   on the item to edit.
   and this is why the value are not shown in the the form when you open the item.

There is no way to do this in onchange event because there is no way to pass the list
of the field to the tree of the first o2m.
what i mean is :

```
        o2m1_id            o2m2_id
model.1 -------> model.2 --------> model.3(field1, field2)
```

in the view of `model.1` you can create a special tree for `o2m1_id` and put the field `o2m2_id` there.
but this is useless because when you open the form fo `o2m1_id` you will find that the `o2m2_id` contains 
records but with empty (field1, field2). and this is because values of field1, field2 returned by onchange event
are ignored, this two field are not in the view of `model.1` that receives them.